# how to remove directory name from the attachment name in php

Tags: php

i have a small issue. i had upload a screen shot of a email that has an attachment sent by using php.but in the attachment name there is the directory name as "upload./" i want to remove that part. how can i do that?

Thank you.[image]

```
$message = $mes;
                echo $message;

                //echo $message;
                $subject = $coursetitle;
                $headers .= 'Cc: gayani@amdt.lk' . "\r\n";

                ini_set("SMTP", "mail.amdt.lk");
                ini_set("sendmail_from", "info@amdt.lk");

                // boundary 
                $semi_rand = md5(time());
                $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

                // headers for attachment 
                $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

                // multipart boundary 
                $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

                // preparing attachments




                        for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
                            $file = fopen($dir.$files[$x],"rb");
                            $data = fread($file,filesize($dir.$files[$x]));
                            fclose($file);
                            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                            $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$dir.$files[$x]\"\n" . 
                            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$dir.$files[$x]\"\n" . 
                            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                        }



                // send
                //echo $message;
               $ok = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
               if ($ok) {
                 echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>";
                } else {
                 echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>";
              }
```

Comment: posting without source code couldn't resolve your question. must be specific. this post could be closed. You receive dot (.) because are on a string "." or under '.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it yourself...

```
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$dir.$files[$x]\"\n" 
                                                    ^^^^
```

that's the filename as it should appear in the client browser... it has nothing to do with where the file is on your server, or what its name is on your server. That's purely for the remote user's information.

In the greater scheme of things... don't build your own mime messages, or use mail(). Mime is painful to get right, when there's perfectly good libraries like PHPMailer and Swiftmailer that do all of that for you with far less code.

Comment: yep i agreed with you Mr.eicto  Thank you very much Mr Marc B

Answer (score 2):

Use [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function:

```
$file="upload./file.jpg";
$basename=basename($file);
$dirname=dirname($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = str_replace("upload./", "", $string);
```

Thats all :)